# Get Object from IList<> by Uniquiness of the Property specified

Tags: c#, .net

Here will explain in detail:
I have

```
public class Season
    {
        #region Public Variables

        private int _id;
        private string _seasonName;
        private int _startMonth;

        #endregion

        #region Public Properties 

        public int Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }

        public int StartMonth
        {
            get { return _startMonth; }
            set { _startMonth = value; }
        }

        public string SeasonName
        {
            get { return _seasonName; }
            set { _seasonName = value; }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Public Constructor

        public Season()
        {
            this._initialize();
        }

        public Season(string pSeasonName, int _pStartMonth,int pID)
        {
            this._initialize(pSeasonName, _pStartMonth, pID);
        }

        #endregion

    }
```

Next I have as show below

```
IList<Season> seaosns = new List<Season>();
seaosns.Add(new Season("Summer", 4, 1));
seaosns.Add(new Season("Winter", 6, 2));
seaosns.Add(new Season("MidSummer", 10, 1));
```

Here i need to check , if Ids are repeated in Ilist Items. This can be done by using For Loop, but need to know is there any other solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Just to clarify your question. You want to get a Season instance with a unique ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most appropriate way to do that is to store the items (either instead, or in addition) in a `Dictionary<int,Season>`, using the unique property (`Id`) as a key in the dictionary. Then you have an `O(1)` lookup both to test existence, and to fetch by key (`Id`). Note, however, that a dictionary ***is not ordered*** - meaning, it does not guarantee to respect either insertion order, or key order. The order *is not defined* - so if you need them in a particular order you might need to hold that separately.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) instead of a list! A set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements, and whose elements are in no particular order. You can provide a custom IEqualityComparer for determining the uniqueness your seasons.

```
var seaosns = new HashSet<Season>(seasonsEqualityComparer);
seaosns.Add(new Season("Summer", 4, 1));
seaosns.Add(new Season("Winter", 6, 2));
seaosns.Add(new Season("MidSummer", 10, 1)); // returns false...
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use an `IDictionary` instead of an `IList`, then duplicate keys are not allowed. You could use `Season.Id` as the key. Using a [`Lookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb460184.aspx) would allow you duplicate elements, so you could iterate the keys and check how many elements are associated with it.

Comment: Annoyingly, the standard `Lookup<,>` is immutable - makes it of limited use (although writing a mutable lookup equivalent is not hard). However, the question seems to suggest the key is unique, so `[I]Dictionary<,>` would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to **check**, try this:

```
var hasDuplicates = list.GroupBy(season => season.Id).Any(groupping => groupping.Count() > 1);
```

But if you want to get collection, that is initially without duplicates, use HashSet or Dictionary, as the others said, or make subclass from Collection which wouldn't allow to add duplicates.